# allocate unified memory in my program. aftering running, it throws CUDA Error:out of memory,but still has free memory

Tags: cuda, nested, out-of-memory

Before asking this, I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642162/out-of-memory-error-throw-by-cudamalloc-but-still-has-free-memory) , which is similar to mine.

Here I will provide my program in detail.

```
#define N 70000
#define M 1000

class ObjBox
{public:

    int oid; float x; float y; float ts};

class Bucket
{public:

    int bid; int nxt; ObjBox *arr_obj; int nO;}

int main()
{

   Bucket *arr_bkt;

   cudaMallocManaged(&arr_bkt, N * sizeof(Bucket));

   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)

   {

       arr_bkt[i].bid = i; 

       arr_bkt[i].nxt = -1;

       arr_bkt[i].nO = 0;

       cudaError_t r = cudaMallocManaged(&(arr_bkt[i].arr_obj), M * sizeof(ObjBox));

       if (r != cudaSuccess)

       {

           printf("CUDA Error on %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(r));

           exit(0);

       }

       for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)

       {

           arr_bkt[i].arr_obj[j].oid = -1;

           arr_bkt[i].arr_obj[j].x = -1;

           arr_bkt[i].arr_obj[j].y = -1;

           arr_bkt[i].arr_obj[j].ts = -1;

        }

   }

   cout << "Bucket Array Initial Completed..." << endl;

   cudaFree(arr_bkt);

   return 0;

}
```

In my main program, I allocate an array of type Bucket,which has a nested array ObjBox. There are totally N(70000) Bucket in the array, M(1000) ObjBox in each Bucket. I can compile my program normally and get out of memory error when running,the error lies in  the line `cudaError_t r = cudaMallocManaged(&(arr_bkt[i].arr_obj), M * sizeof(ObjBox));`

I have tried to solve the question for long, here are some point I find:

1, When N is smaller, such ad 30000, 40000， 60000 even, the program can work normally.That is, it can allocate so much unified memory in a structure;

2, There are still many free memory.In my server,there are 16G host memory and 11G GPU global memory. But in this program, the Bucket array consumes nearly

```
 N * M * sizeof(ObjBox) = 70000 * 1000 * 16Byte = 1120M;
```

3, The value M nearly has nothing to do with the out of memory error; When N remains the same(70000), M decreases to 100, the program breaks too;

The type of my GPU is Tesla K40c, I have present my question to my tutor, and she present this to her friend, her friend runs the program in her Tesla K20 with CUDA version 7.0, it works and can normally allocate the structure.

How is it going?how can I allocate the structure in my Tesla K40c?
My tutor think there might be some limited settings in the GPU driver settings,
but I can't solve it yet;

Comment: by using unified memory as you sugggested, I have solved my previous question, can you give me some advice on my new question？@Robert

Answer (score 2):

If I modify your code with some instrumentation, like this:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

#define N 70000
#define M 1000

class ObjBox
{
    public:

        int oid; 
        float x; 
        float y; 
        float ts;
};

class Bucket
{
    public:

        int bid; 
        int nxt; 
        ObjBox *arr_obj; 
        int nO;
};

int main()
{

    Bucket *arr_bkt;
    cudaMallocManaged(&arr_bkt, N * sizeof(Bucket));

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        arr_bkt[i].bid = i; 
        arr_bkt[i].nxt = -1;
        arr_bkt[i].nO = 0;

        size_t allocsz = size_t(M) * sizeof(ObjBox);
        cudaError_t r = cudaMallocManaged(&(arr_bkt[i].arr_obj), allocsz);
        if (r != cudaSuccess) {
            printf("CUDA Error on %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(r));
            exit(0);
        } else {
            size_t total_mem, free_mem;
            cudaMemGetInfo(&free_mem, &total_mem);
            std::cout << i << ":Allocated " << allocsz;
            std::cout << " Currently " << free_mem << " bytes free" << std::endl;
        } 

        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            arr_bkt[i].arr_obj[j].oid = -1;
            arr_bkt[i].arr_obj[j].x = -1;
            arr_bkt[i].arr_obj[j].y = -1;
            arr_bkt[i].arr_obj[j].ts = -1;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Bucket Array Initial Completed..." << std::endl;
    cudaFree(arr_bkt);

    return 0;
}
```

and compile and run it on a unified memory system with 16Gb physical host memory and 2Gb physical device memory with the Linux 352.39 driver, I get this:

```
0:Allocated 16000 Currently 2099871744 bytes free
1:Allocated 16000 Currently 2099871744 bytes free
2:Allocated 16000 Currently 2099871744 bytes free
3:Allocated 16000 Currently 2099871744 bytes free
4:Allocated 16000 Currently 2099871744 bytes free
5:Allocated 16000 Currently 2099871744 bytes free
6:Allocated 16000 Currently 2099871744 bytes free
7:Allocated 16000 Currently 2099871744 bytes free
8:Allocated 16000 Currently 2099871744 bytes free
9:Allocated 16000 Currently 2099871744 bytes free
....
....
....
65445:Allocated 16000 Currently 1028161536 bytes free
65446:Allocated 16000 Currently 1028161536 bytes free
65447:Allocated 16000 Currently 1028161536 bytes free
65448:Allocated 16000 Currently 1028161536 bytes free
65449:Allocated 16000 Currently 1028161536 bytes free
65450:Allocated 16000 Currently 1028161536 bytes free
65451:Allocated 16000 Currently 1028161536 bytes free
CUDA Error on out of memory
```

i.e. it reports out of memory with plenty of free memory remaining on the device.

I think the key to understanding this is the *number* of allocations, at the failure point, rather than their size. 65451 is suspiciously close to 65535 (i.e. 2^16). Allowing for the internal memory allocations that the runtime makes, I am going to guess that there is some sort of accidental or deliberate limit on the total number of memory managed memory allocations to 65535.

I would be very interested to see whether you can reproduce this. If you can, I would be contemplating filing a bug report with NVIDIA.

Comment: I concur and have filed a bug internally with NVIDIA.  However I don't know for sure that it is a defect yet; in any event it appears to be an undocumented limit.  My suggestion as a workaround would be to arrange your programs so that they don't require more than 65000 managed memory allocations.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Thanks for the confirmation. I wouldn't ever imagine writing code that required 65k malloc calls, but that's just me :)

Comment: According to my testing, the issue appears to be fixed in CUDA 8.0RC.  That is, using the above code, with `M=100` and CUDA 8.0RC, the program will run to completion successfully without throwing an error, over 70,000 calls to `cudaMallocManaged`.  I have not tested for a higher limit, if any.

Comment: The limit on CUDA 8RC, if there is one, appears to be higher than 1000000, according to my testing [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38078737/cudamallocmanaged-returns-out-of-memory-despite-enough-free-space).  It's possible that the limit now is simply memory space, not the number of allocations, but I haven't proven that.