# cudaMallocManaged() returns "out of memory" despite enough free space

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory, cuda

I'm trying to build a tree structure that I want to use in a Cuda kernel. For that I allocate memory with cudaMallocManaged() so that Cuda copies the structure to the GPU when needed. But no matter the size of the structure, I get an "out of memory" error at about the 65407th memory allocation, even though plenty of memory space is still available on both CPU and GPU memory.

Can anyone help me and point to the specific boundary that is limiting my program? Is this a hard limit in Cuda or did I miss a setting in the OS configuration?

I'm using a GeForce GTX 980 with Cuda 7.5 on a Ubuntu 14.04 desktop.

Here is an example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

typedef struct Tree {
    u_int64_t       foo;
    struct Tree     *left_child;
    struct Tree     *right_child;
} Tree;

void printMemInfo(size_t counter) {
  size_t freemem;
  size_t totalmem;
  cudaMemGetInfo(&freemem, &totalmem);
  printf("%4.2fMB/ %4.2fMB (Free/ Total), #Nodes: %lu\n",
    freemem / (1024 * 1024.0),
    totalmem / (1024 * 1024.0),
    counter);
}

void printCudaError(cudaError_t error) {
  if (error != cudaSuccess) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s:%d, ", __FILE__, __LINE__);
    fprintf(stderr, "code: %d, reason: %s\n", error,
    cudaGetErrorString(error));
    exit(1);
  }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  cudaSetDevice(0);
  size_t numnodes = 1000000;
  Tree *node[numnodes];

  for(size_t i = 0; i < numnodes; i++) {
    printMemInfo(i);
    cudaError_t error = cudaMallocManaged( (void **) &node[i], sizeof(Tree) );
    printCudaError(error);
  }

  cudaDeviceReset();
  return 0;
}
```

Which returns:

```
...
3393.63MB/ 4095.31MB (Free/ Total), #Nodes: 65405
3393.63MB/ 4095.31MB (Free/ Total), #Nodes: 65406
3393.63MB/ 4095.31MB (Free/ Total), #Nodes: 65407
Error: memory_problem/test.cu:23, code: 2, reason: out of memory
```

Comment: Are you sure you got enough stack space to hold one million `Tree*` variables? Does the problem go away if you change the code to `static Tree *node[numnodes]`? If so, you have a stack overflow.

Comment: Not the problem, but you should't cast here: `cudaMallocManaged( (void **) &node[i]`, you need an intermediate `void*` pointer.

Comment: This is a known limitation of `cudaMallocManaged`.  The overall dynamic allocation limit for this is approximately 65535.

Comment: @RobertCrovella If it is a dupe why not close it as one?

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Thanks for that information. Do you have any reference? I didn't find any limits in the cuda online documentation.

Comment: No, I mentioned in the linked dupe that it appears to be an undocumented limit.  I've already filed a bug with NVIDIA.  You're welcome to file your own bug with NVIDIA at developer.nvidia.com -- I would encourage you to do so.

Comment: The behavior appears to be different in CUDA 8RC (possibly fixed).  If you are facing this issue, I recommend that you first update to CUDA 8RC, as the limit appears to be some number higher than 65535 now. I've also updated the linked duplicate with this info.  I would suggest evaluating your code with CUDA 8RC before filing any bugs.  Issues that are fixed in a newer version of CUDA won't receive much attention from a bug standpoint.

Comment: I ran the code in this question on a CUDA 8.0RC system, CentOS7, Tesla K20X (6GB).  It appeared to run successfully through 1000000 iterations/allocations.  The final printout line: `1716.62MB/ 5700.38MB (Free/ Total), #Nodes: 999999`